# Set up OpenVPN (Mullvad)?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN virtual adapter for my Mullvad VPN service (which is excellent, by the way).

Anyway I'm in the Network Connections utility/panel/applet/whatever-it-is and I am trying to figure this out. I specified that I wish to create an OpenVPN connection and it is asking me for some settings.

From Mullvad I downloaded my linux settings as a compressed folder and I have some files inside a folder named as my user-name (user-number, actually): ca.crt, crl.pem, mullvad.crt, mullvad.key, and mullvad_linux.conf.

The OpenVPN window is asking me for some files, but I don't know which are which. It is set to use Certificates(TLS) and is asking me for User Certificate, CA Certificate, and Private Key. (It also wants a Private Key Password in a password-entry box.)

How do I successfully set this up? Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- User Certificate => mullvad.crt
- CA Certificate => ca.crt
- Private Key => mullvad.key

The Private Key Password is only required if the Private Key is encrypted, if you don't have a password probably it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. 

For the sake of other people who may find this I thought I should mention that 'Gateway' must be set to `openvpn.mullvad.net`.